# Firebase: No matching allow statements

Tags: firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I am trying to create a subcollection inside my users collection right after my user has been logged in. After the creation, a document should be created inside this new subcollection ("lieferadresse") The problem I encounter is, that I always get the following error:

> Write failed at users/nBmt6Ty2VRNQZCPfCi1ptb2rVAkH/lieferadresse/XAj3zGkNTjJu9Ts8ZgyQ: Status{code=PERMISSION_DENIED, description=No matching allow statements, cause=null}

I have zero clue, why this error happens as I allowed the users to create and update their documents. Here are my rules:

### Security Rules

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
      
      match /users/{userID=**} {
        allow write: if (request.auth.uid == userID);
        allow update: if (request.auth.uid == userID);
      }
  }
}
```

### Code

```
override suspend fun registerWithEmailAndPw(
    email: String,
    password: String,
    user: User,
    deliveryAddress: UserDeliveryAddress?,
): Flow<LoginStateEvent> = flow {
    
    dbAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).await()

    createUserIfNotExist(user)

    dbFirestore
        .collection(FIREBASE_USER_BASE_PATH)
        .document(dbAuth.currentUser!!.uid)
        .collection(FIREBASE_USER_DELIVERY_ADRESS)
        .add(userDeliveryNetworkEntityMapper.mapToEntity(deliveryAddress!!)) // this gives me an error
        .await()

}

private suspend fun createUserIfNotExist(user: UserNetworkEntity) {
    val uid = dbAuth.currentUser!!.uid
    val document = dbFirestore.collection(FIREBASE_USER_BASE_PATH).document(uid).get().await()
    if (!document.exists()) {
        dbFirestore.collection(FIREBASE_USER_BASE_PATH).document(uid).set(user)
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share your whole rules file.

Comment: @TarikHuber Updated, only have the rules above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained in the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-structure?authuser=0#recursive_wildcards), "when using the recursive wildcard syntax, the wildcard variable will contain **the entire matching path segment**, even if the document is located in a deeply nested subcollection".

Therefore, with your example, the `userID` variable has the following value: `nBmt6Ty2VRNQZCPfCi1ptb2rVAkH/lieferadresse/XAj3zGkNTjJu9Ts8ZgyQ`

---

You could use the [`split`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.String?authuser=0#split) method to extract the value, but IMO the best is to write a rule corresponding to the exact Document path, as follows:

```
  match /users/{userID}/lieferadresse/{docID} {
    allow write: if (request.auth.uid == userID);
    allow update: if (request.auth.uid == userID);
  }
```

Comment: So lets say I have a base collection "users". Every document in this collection represents a user. Now, every user can have it's own subcollection "lieferadresse". If I write a rule inside "match /users/{users}/lieferadresse/{userID}" like "allow write: if request.auth.uid = users" does that mean, that only the user itself can update its own subcollection "lieferadresse"?

Comment: It is not clear to me which part of the `users/{users}/lieferadresse/{userID}` path is corresponding to the exact userID. Do you assign the userID value (from the Auth service) to the doc in the `users` collection or to the doc in the `lieferadresse` collection?

Comment: To the doc in the users collection. For example, when a user creates an account and has the id "12345", it gets a document with the id "12345" inside the users collection

Comment: Ok, so you should do as follows: `match /users/{userID}/lieferadresse/{docID}` and  `allow write: if request.auth.uid = userID`. You have to use the wildcard in the path that corresponds to the user ID value.